# Cannot fix "Server Error in '/' Application" ServiceStack

Tags: exception, servicestack

I am having a hard time solving this issue. I am still introducing myself to ServiceStack and while trying to add a MySql Database to my web application (this could be completely unrelated to the error) I have come accross an error stopping my application from running. I have undid a lot of my steps but cannot get back to when it worked properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error:

```
Method 'get_IsLocal' in type 
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpRequestWrapper' from assembly 
'ServiceStack, Version=3.9.37.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current 
web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception 
can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[TypeLoadException: Method 'get_IsLocal' in type
 'ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpRequestWrapper' from assembly
 'ServiceStack, Version=3.9.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does 
not have an implementation.]
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.GetHandler
(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +0
System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.
IExecutionStep.Execute() +346
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
completedSynchronously) +155
```

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using ServiceStack.Configuration;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Validation;
using ServiceStack.FluentValidation;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceModel;
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.Common.Utils;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;
using ServiceStack.Common;

namespace SampleHello2
{
    public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
            return (userName == "Ian" && password == "pass");
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
        {
            //Fill the IAuthSession with data which you want to retrieve in the app eg:
            session.FirstName = "Ian Mc Garry";
            //...

            //Important: You need to save the session!
            authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
        }
    }


    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public class HelloAppHost : AppHostBase
        {
            //Tell Service Stack the name of your application and where to find your web services
            public HelloAppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
            {
                //Enable Features
                Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
                Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                    new IAuthProvider[] {
                        new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
                    }
                ));

                //register any dependencies your services use, e.g:
                container.RegisterValidators(typeof(HelloValidator).Assembly);

                //Database
                //string conn = "Server=host;Port=3306;Database=db;UserId=user;Password=pass;";
                //container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(conn, MySqlDialectProvider.Instance));
            }
        }

        //Initialize your application singleton
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new HelloAppHost().Init();
        }
    }

}
```

Again any help would be greatly appreciated. The problem is probably very clear but I cannot solve it. Also I do not have enough experience to understand the issue (error/stack trace) myself. I see it refers to the package `ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;` I am using but that is all I can garner.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have dirty .dlls. Make sure you update all NuGet packages, if the issue still persists clean out the NuGet `/packages` folder and try again.

Note the latest version (as of 6 March 2013) of [MySql OrmLite](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql) package is v3.9.39.

Comment: Thanks for this. Away from my pc at the moment but I will let you know how it goes asap.

Comment: Just updating the packages fixed everything. Thanks very much for the support.